# Minify / Uglify embedded JavaScript in Symfony/Twig response

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig, assetic, uglifyjs

Compressing linked `JavaScript` and `CSS` files is no big deal when using `Assetic` in my `Symfony 2.8` project. But what about scripts that are directly embedded in the page using a `script` tag. These scripts are not modified in any way.

Is it possible to compress/modify/uglify these scripts as well?

Of course I could simply move these scripts into separat files and thus apply the `Assetic` filters to them as well. But in some cases it is just handy to have the scripts directly within the HTML / Twig template.

So, is there any existing solution to filter these scripts without moving them?

Comment: in most cases you can outsource 99% of the code into separate files, include them with assetic in your twig template leaving only a small portion of javascript as inline script. I use that approach mostly for dynamic configuration parameters, initialization JSON data etc.

Comment: Sure, this is absolutely correct. However in my project I would estimated, that 5-10% of the code is used within HTML / Twig. But it does not matter if its 1%, 5% or 50%. In some cases inline code is just easier to handle. Thus the question is **how to minify / uglify this code, without moving to separat files**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I found no solution for this, I finally managed to create my own: Add a custom tag to my (existing) Twig extension to apply Assetics `uglifyJS2` filter to the embedded scripts:

**Step 1:** Create a Twig `TokenParser` and `Node`

```
class UglifyTokenParser extends Twig_TokenParser {
    private $enabled;    

    public function __construct($enabled = true) {
        $this->enabled = (bool) $enabled;
    }


    public function parse(Twig_Token $token) {
        $lineNumber = $token->getLine();

        $this->parser->getStream()->expect(Twig_Token::BLOCK_END_TYPE);
        $body = $this->parser->subparse(function (Twig_Token $token) {
            return $token->test('enduglify');
        }, true);

        $this->parser->getStream()->expect(Twig_Token::BLOCK_END_TYPE);
        if ($this->enabled) {
            $node = new UglifyNode($body, $lineNumber, $this->getTag());
            return $node;
        }

        return $body;
    }    


    public function getTag() {
        return 'uglify';
    }
}

class UglifyNode extends \Twig_Node {
    public function __construct(Twig_Node $body, $lineNumber, $tag = 'uglify') {
        parent::__construct(array('body' => $body), array(), $lineNumber, $tag);
    }

    public function compile(Twig_Compiler $compiler) {      
        $compiler
            ->addDebugInfo($this)
            ->write("ob_start();\n")                
            ->subcompile($this->getNode('body'))
            ->write("echo \$context['_uglifier']->uglify(trim(ob_get_clean()));\n");
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** Add the `Uglifier` class, which is used by the `Node` to pass the content to the Assetic `UglifyJS2Filter`

```
class Uglifier {
    private $filter;
    private $asset;
    private $enabled;

    public function __construct(FilterInterface $filter, $endabled) {
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->asset = new UglifierAsset(array($this->filter));
        $this->enabled = $endabled;
    }

    public function uglify($content) {
        if ($this->enabled) {
            $this->asset->loadContent($content);
            $uglified = $this->asset->dump();       
            return $uglified;
        } else {
            return $content;
        }
    }
}


class UglifierAsset extends BaseAsset {
    public function __construct($filters = array())  {
        parent::__construct($filters);
    }

    private $theContent;
    public function loadContent($content) {
        $this->theContent = $content;
        $this->load();
    }

    public function load(FilterInterface $additionalFilter = null) {
        $this->doLoad($this->theContent);
    }

    public function getLastModified() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**Step 3:** Create `Uglifier` as sService, pass it to the `Twig Extension` and implement custom tag within the extension

```
app.twig_extension:
    class: AppBundle\Twig\AppExtension
    public: false
    arguments: [ "@app.twig_extension.uglifier" ]
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }


app.twig_extension.uglifier:
    class: AppBundle\Twig\uglify\Uglifier
    arguments: [ "@assetic.filter.uglifyjs2", "%twig_extension.unglifier.enabled%" ]


class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension implements \Twig_Extension_GlobalsInterface {
    private $uglifier;
    public function __construct(Uglifier $uglifier) {
        $this->uglifier = $uglifier;
    }

    public function getGlobals() {      
        return array(
            '_uglifier' => $this->uglifier,
        );
    }

    public function getTokenParsers() {
        return array(new UglifyTokenParser());
    }
}
```

**Step 4:** Wrap embedded scripts with the new `{% uglify %} tag

```
{# before #}
<script type="text/javascript">
    // some JS
</script>

{# after #}
<script type="text/javascript">
    {% uglify %}
        // some JS
    {% enduglify %}
</script>
```

**DONE**